# Equivalency of Debian Backport vs build from source?

Tags: debian, backports

I am looking to use Node.js in a Debian Wheezy Stable system. Of course it is not available as a package, so my choices are:

1. Compile from source
2. Load from Wheezy back ports

My question is basically: Given that either way I end up with an executable, is this fundamentally the same thing? Or are there benefits either way?

The reason I am asking this is I want to use Node.js on a minimalistic system where I don't want to have to install development tools.

Comment: You can also back-port Debian packages yourself  if you want to have full control or if the pacakge you want is not (yet) available in the backports repository. You can do this on a separate system. Sometimes small modifications on the build-dependencies of the package you want to backport are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, those are the same things.

However, when using a package from backports, you can know that the package has been tested so that it works specifically with the Debian system.

Also, the package will be installed according to Debian specific rules, that is, the start / stop scripts are made according to Debian standards, package files are installed to locations according to Debian standard etc.

The only benefit with compiling from source would be that you will receive the most current version that way.

I would always use the backports version, it makes administration so much easier.